Github Actions fails to find UnitTest.csproj
I'm currently trying to set up a GitHub actions such that when a PR is made to the developing branch, a series unit test runs on the PR. This is a dotnet application, and here is the dot.yml:
name: .NET
on:
 push:
   branches: [ "developing" ]
 pull_request:
   branches: [ "developing" ]


jobs:
 build:


runs-on: windows-latest


steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v4
- name: Setup .NET
  uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
  with:
    dotnet-version: 8.0.x
- name: Restore dependencies
  run: dotnet restore
- name: Build
  run: dotnet build --no-restore
- name: Test
  run: dotnet test --no-build --verbosity normal

Here is how the project is structured:

When I test out the actions it fails, and I get the following message:
Run dotnet restore
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.302\NuGet.targets(414,5): error MSB3202: The project file "D:\a\project\UnitTest\UnitTest.csproj" was not found. [D:\a\project\project\project.sln]
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

I'm not sure how to resolve this, the UnitTest folder is in the project, and it is only in the developing branch, it is not in the Main branch.  I have tried adding run: dotnet restore project/ but that didn't help. Searching online for solution told me that the file name could be too long, but I don't think that's the case with my project. When I run dotnet restore locally everything works. Any idea what I should do?

How do you run it locally? Have you verified that it exists in your workflow by listing its contents and path? Please add this info in your question. Also, the workflow is your question is not formatted correctly. Please reformat that as well. Thanks!
